# Naming variables describing the same thing but of different type

Tags: naming-conventions

What is a commonly accepted approach in variable naming when dealing with variables that are of different type but describe the same thing?

```
private String  contentFolder    = "/tmp/";
private File    contentDirectory = new File(contentFolder);
```

The above seems sloppy. But what is better?

```
private String  contentDirectoryStr = "/tmp/";
private File    contentDirectory    = new File(contentDirectoryStr);
```

Looks just as bad.

**What is a common convention you follow to describe same things of different type?**

Thought you can of course get `String` from `File`, for the purposes of this question, assume you legitimately need both a `String` and a `File` in your class.

Comment: def avoid your #2 Hungarian notation option http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to use the same name, but differentiate based on the type.

Example:

```
private String  contentDirStr  = "/tmp/";
private File    contentDirFile = new File(contentDirStr);
```

Of course it would better to not have two objects representing the same thing, but if you really need to, that's how I would go about naming them.